# How do you extend a class with hardcoded properties and no constructor arguments in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, javascript-objects, prototypal-inheritance

I'm learning how classes work in JS and I'm trying to figure out how you can create a sub-class from a class with no constructor arguments and only hardcoded values

I just want the boss class to inherit the hardcoded properties of NPC, I'm changing the array in Boss but I want the logic for the weapon selection to stay the same.

```js
class NPC {
  constructor() {
    this.weaponsArray = ['Sword', 'Gun', 'Axe']
    this.weapon = this.weaponsArray[Math.floor(Math.random * 3)]

  }
}

class Boss extends NPC {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.weaponsArray = ['Mongo Hammer', 'Sword of Death', 'Gun of Pity']

  }
}


let bossguy = new Boss()

console.log(bossguy.weapon)
```

Comment: Your question title already spells out the correct way to do this: use constructor parameters! Why are you trying to avoid them?

Comment: Idk because I wanted to the class to instantiate objects based on hardcoded values built in to the class not something that would be “passed in”

Comment: But they are not actually hardcoded if `Boss` has different values than `NPC`, so `NPC` should definitely accept them as arguments, they *do* sometimes come from outside of `NPC`. You still can default them of course, but fundamentally they need to be passed in.

Answer (score 2):

I created a getter function to get weapon property, it will be set weapon if it is not set before:

```js
class NPC {
  constructor() {
    this.weaponsArray = ['Sword', 'Gun', 'Axe'];
    //   this.weapon = this.weaponsArray[Math.floor(Math.random()* 3)]
  }
  getWeapon() {
    this.weapon = this.weapon || this.weaponsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
    return this.weapon;
  }
}

class Boss extends NPC {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.weaponsArray = ['Mongo Hammer', 'Sword of Death', 'Gun of Pity'];
  }
}

let bossguy = new Boss();
console.log(bossguy.getWeapon());
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could add an optional `weapons` argument to your constructor. You don't even have to extend the class to get a new type of NPC. I would also extract the generation of the weapons into its own function, so the logic is separate from the constructor. This way you can change the weapon by calling `someNPC.selectWeapon()`. The function would work even, if you extended the class

Example:

```js
class NPC {
  constructor(weapons) {
    if (arguments.length == 0) {
      // No arguments were passed
      weapons = ['Sword', 'Gun', 'Axe']
    }

    this.weaponsArray = weapons
    this.weapon = this.selectWeapon()
  }
  selectWeapon() {
    return this.weaponsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.weaponsArray.length)]
  }
}


let defaultNPC = new NPC()
let bossguy = new NPC(['Mongo Hammer', 'Sword of Death', 'Gun of Pity'])

console.log(bossguy.weapon)
console.log(defaultNPC.weapon)
```

If you insist on extending the class:

```
class Boss extends NPC {
  constructor() {
    super(['Mongo Hammer', 'Sword of Death', 'Gun of Pity'])
    this.weaponsArray = this.selectWeapon()
  }
}
```